# Bulk upload images, generating a seperate page for each image

Tags: entries, assets, categories, url, image

Building a photography website for a client, need a way to bulk upload images, much like using the assets field. I want these to be grouped into different sets by entry or category. So that I can apply whatever fields I need to the set then loop through these images based on set in the Front-End.

The method I have tried is using entries and having an assets field to upload the images. The problem I am having is I also need to have each image generate it's own seperate URL, meaning a template page for the set of images and then another template for each image in that set.

Is there a way to accomplish this using Craft's core features?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your main image index template, you can iterated through all of the assets and generate URLs yourself like this:

```
{% for asset in assets %}
    <a href="/photos/photo-detail/{{ asset.slug }}">{{ asset.title }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Then set up a custom route for `/photos/photo-detail/`(slug) and point it at the `photo-detail.twig` template. In that template, you can get the slug for the asset via `craft.request.getSegment(3)` and then look up the asset via the slug.

Comment: This has worked perfectly, I see now how you can use routes and Twig together to get alot done. Very powerful stuff. Thanks!!